# Highcharts-Angular image export with styledMode enabled not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I have an angular project that uses highcharts and the [highcharts-angular](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) wrapper, and I have been running into an error when exporting an image with chart options that contain `styledMode: true`. When I try to export an image, no download occurs and the browser console shows `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property`. This error happens only in Safari (I am running v.16.4 of Safari); I do not have this error in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge).

I have tried running the highcharts-angular wrapper's demo app locally; making the changes to one of the chart options to enable `styledMode` and get the same error there as well. So I opened a [thread](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=50680) on Highchart's support forums about this issue. A mod responded, with a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-95qpfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the same sample chart, and exporting the image works fine there for me, even in Safari. I have **not** been able to reproduce the error in stackblitz.

I have since tried starting a new angular project (with angular-cli v. 15.2.6, node v.18.16.0) [[github link](https://github.com/vcward/highcharts-test)] with the following dependencies and versions:

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.6
├── @angular/animations@15.2.7
├── @angular/cli@15.2.6
├── @angular/common@15.2.7
├── @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.7
├── @angular/compiler@15.2.7
├── @angular/core@15.2.7
├── @angular/forms@15.2.7
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@15.2.7
├── @angular/platform-browser@15.2.7
├── @angular/router@15.2.7
├── @types/jasmine@4.3.1
├── highcharts-angular@3.1.2
├── highcharts@10.3.3
├── jasmine-core@4.5.0
├── karma-chrome-launcher@3.1.1
├── karma-coverage@2.2.0
├── karma-jasmine-html-reporter@2.0.0
├── karma-jasmine@5.1.0
├── karma@6.4.1
├── rxjs@7.8.0
├── tslib@2.5.0
├── typescript@4.9.5
└── zone.js@0.12.0
```

When trying to export the chart image, I do still get the `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property` error in Safari when running the project locally. I am not sure if this is an issue with highcharts, or if I have a setting wrong somewhere in the angular project itself.

Comment: I see you've already reported the bug to the official wrapper repo, so the thread will continue there. But it seems quite difficult to debug so you have to be patient.

Issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/352

Comment: Were you able to get any headway with this?

Comment: Apologies for the late response, but no. I just updated my project to the latest version of highcharts and highcharts-angular; however, I am still seeing the error when using the image export in Safari.